# HDMI not connected to discrete graphics

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, hdtv

This is from internet: "(the gaming laptop) has the Type-C port going to the Nvidia discrete graphics, while the HDMI port goes to the Vega iGPU".

I am planning to connect this laptop to a budget 4K TV. I think that TV supports only 60Hz but, still, I am interested in using 4k resolution for games as long as discrete Nvidia can support it.

Do I have to buy "HDMI to USB Type-C" cable to be able to play games via discrete graphics? Or the cable is not important and regular HDMI-HDMI cable of enough quality will do exactly the same?

If using "HDMI to USB Type-C", do I have to do some special setup in BIOS/UEFI or on Win10 or it will be recognized automagically?

EDIT: The main question is: what is the meaning of the info about "which port is connected to which GPU". This is usualy noted by testers and omitted by manufacturers. When you are buying a gaming laptop, is this an important data or not?

Comment: USB Type-C to HDMI. Cables are described by the signal path.

Comment: Please add your laptop’s make and model to the question.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15/specifications/

Answer (score 0):

> This is from internet: "(the gaming laptop) has the Type-C port going to the Nvidia discrete graphics, while the HDMI port goes to the Vega iGPU".

No source? Seriously? Just some rando on the Internet who could have a hidden agenda to promote some fascist ideologies… or just be less versed with technology than you but use more terms they do not completely understand. Do you take your laptop apart to jumper hardware IDs and set IRQs?

Think about this: How is your internal display connected? … To make use of both? If not, why waste precious CPU silicon area and energy? That area could be used to have twice the amount of CPU cores.

Could it be through [GPU switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU_switching)? Could this question have been [answered](https://support.ubisoft.com/en-gb/faqs/000027100/Switching-to-the-laptop-s-dedicated-GPU/) by a company in the gaming business? I'd try that before buying new stuff.

Comment: Well, I am used not to name company names and products nor make a link to other forums and sources... as far as the question can be technically unambiguous. Morevover, I know about GPU switching and I am familiar with Win10 application where you select which GPU will be used by which application. However, I have never tried HDMI output for gaming and I am curious about, what this small note about "which port is connected to which GPU" means for the end user. This is usualy noted by testers and omitted by manufacturers. So, is this important info or not when you are buying a gaming laptop?